# Installing Virtual Box on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to install virtual box on Ubuntu 11.10

I tried the procedure given in following link:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/virtualbox-4-1-6-released-and-ubuntu-11-1011-04-installation-instructions-included.html

But, when I do sudo apt-get update it is showing failed message as follows:

W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/oneiric/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

If anyone aware of this bug please help me soon.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've just installed VirtualBox 4.1.8 on my Ubuntu 11.10 (desktop), but I've used another way (so, it wont solve your bug, it will just help you to install VB) :

- Go to [Virtual Box Linux Downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)
- Download the .deb file corresponding to your platform (i386/amd64)
- Open the .deb. The Software center will start, and will allow you to install VB

Comment: Having same problem.  There are many similar reports on the web.

sudo apt-get clean did nothing.  This is a new distro install - no prior versions of VBox.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see the contents of your `source.list`?

One thing you could try is `sudo apt-get clean`